# fscanf won't read first variable in each line

Tags: c++, file, scanf

I am trying to read information from a file, but my code won't read the first input in each line.

This ir my code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
FILE* inFile;
long long int time;
char state, ID[12], name[51];

inFile = fopen("file.i2", "r");

while (fscanf(inFile, "%i %s %s %[^\n]s",&time ,&state, &ID, &name)!=EOF)
        cout << time << ' ' << state << ' ' << ID << ' ' << name << endl;

return 0;
}
```

This is the input:

```
1111 A 01010112345 SomeString1
1112 A 01010154321 SomeString2
1113 A 11111122222 SomeString3
1114 B 12121233333 SomeString4
1115 B 12121233333 SomeString5
```

This is the output:

```
1024 A 01010112345 SomeString1
1024 A 01010154321 SomeString2
1024 A 11111122222 SomeString3
1024 B 12121233333 SomeString4
1024 B 12121233333 SomeString5
```

In my case the output should be the same as the input.

Comment: `%s` will write a null-terminated string, thus causing undefined behaviour since you don't provide sufficient storage.

Comment: You might want to start not lying about the types you pass: `%i` is for `int`, not for `long long int`. If you want to read a `long long int` you'd use `lli`. Since you tagged this question as C++, I'd recommend using `std::ifstream` as that will figure out the necessary conversion automatically. Also, you should check against `4` not `EOF`: the constant `EOF` is only returned if the stream can't even read one element.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I switched %i to %lli and changed the while condition to '... == 4', but the program still returns time as 1024.

Comment: @KerrekSB could you, please, explain where I haven't provided sufficient storage?

Comment: @user3677314 this shoud be char state[2], 'A' + '\0' are 2 chars, why don't you read the answer below?

Comment: @bits_international: ...and it should also be `%1s` etc... but all this information is [contained in the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html), and I'm on break from my copy/paste job until I get back to completing those TPS reports in the office.

Comment: @user3677314 Besides `using namespace std;` and using the various c++ standard includes, what has this question really to do with proper [tag:c++] code??

Comment: @user3677314: yes, there were a lot more issues with your use of `fscanf()` than I spotted immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have undefined behavior as your state is to small when %s format is used (null terminates the string). Also you want to use `%Ld` format to read into long long integer.

```
long long int time;
char state[2], ID[12], name[51];
           ^ 
//         make room for '\0'


while ( fscanf( inFile, "%Ld %1s %11s %50[^\n]s",&time ,&state, &ID, &name) != 4)
        cout << time << ' ' << state << ' ' << ID << ' ' << name << endl;
```

You should however use a [std::ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream). This way you will have less problems with conversion of variables. And note that we now specify number of characters to read by scanf (%2s, %12s, %51s) and that now we test fscanf for `== 4` that is for number of successfully read elements because returned value by scanf is

> Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned, or EOF if read
>   failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: Thank you. I had forgotten about the end symbol in 'state'.

Comment: To my understanding, `%2s` is UB. It should be `%1s`. The null terminator is not included.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt at `fscanf()` is broken in multiple ways:

1. To read a `long long int` you'll need to use the length modifier `ll`. You pass the address of an `long long int` where an `int` is expected. Everything now is undefined behavior.
2. To read a character, the format specifier is `%c` not `%s`.
3. Although not strictly wrong the string don't restrict the size to the length available: to avoid exploits due to buffer overflows you should specify the maximum size.
4. `fscanf()` returns the number of successful conversion. The result `EOF` is returned only if none of the conversions is succcessful, i.e., you should test against `4` rather than `EOF`.

Using the conversion

```
while (fscanf(inFile, "%lli %c %s %[^\n]s",&time ,&state, &ID, &name) == 4) {
    cout << time << ' ' << state << ' ' << ID << ' ' << name << '\n';
}
```

should work OK. I'd recommend using streams for the input instead as these do the conversion automatically:

```
std::ifstream in("file.i2");
while ((in >> time >> state >> std::setw(12) >> ID).getline(name, 51)) {
    cout << time << ' ' << state << ' ' << ID << ' ' << name << '\n';
}
```

That's a lot less error-prone although it is still necessary to set the size when reading strings.